# Sync Yahoo! calendar with Outlook calendar

Tags: yahoo, synchronization

I'd like to sync my Yahoo! calendar with an Outlook calendar. I know how to do this, but after sync, I can't change the meetings anymore. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you syncing them?

Answer (score -1):

You may need a sync plugin which handles meetings or preserve the meeting structures properly. I have tried 2 plugins that work with yahoo and outlook, evo collaborator and caldav synchronizer, the 'evo collaborator' seems to handle meeting properly.